# i Can't convert NSData to NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, json, nsstring, nsdata

I want to try to convert NSData to NSDictionary or NSArray but some how i can't do that but whenever try to convert into NSString it will converted and gating data so any one can know what is mistake ,help me below is code for convert

```
 NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                                   options:0
                                                                            error:nil];
```

Below code for convert into NSString

NSString *str = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

But Problem is that When get this type of data it will converted on array 
**Response**:

> [["superwoman",0],["sugar",0],["sultan trailer",0],["summer",0],["superman",0],["sunday candy",0],["sublime",0],["summer sixteen",0],["superfruit",0],["sultan songs",0]]

but Whenever gat this type of response it will not converted on array formated because of ,[3 on response

**Response:**

> [["ssundee",0],["selena gomez",0],["sia",0],["sorry beyonce",0],["smosh",0],["sweatshirt jacob
>   sartorius",0],["skydoesminecraft",0],["secret life of pets
>   trailer",0,[3]]

Comment: if your conversion returns nil the pass an error reference to NSJSONSerialization and debug.whats in the error

Comment: The last one is not a valid JSON, it's missing a closing "]" at the end.

Comment: I suspect this is being converted from data to JSON in the wrong connection delegate method...  else the server devs are idiots.

Comment: Getting this response from http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?client=youtube&ds=yt&q=%@

Comment: As Droppy says: Either you are processing the JSON before it is complete, in which cause it is your fault, or the server devs produce something that is almost but not quite JSON.

Answer (score 0):

1)You need to take the response in `id` type variable & check the class of response like below.

2)You also need to check if JSON convertion is successful

```
 NSError * error;

 id result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data 
      options:0 error:&error];

if (!error) {

 if([id isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]){
   //Response is Dictonary
   } else if ([id isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]){
   //Response is Array
   } else {
   //any other format
   }

 } else {

  //Handle error

 }
```

Comment: Getting <nil> on result object now i got the some temporary  solution to use of rang and adding into array but it it not good solution

Answer (score 0):

```
try this one

    NSError* error;
                 NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject
                                                                      options:kNilOptions
                                                                        error:&error];
```

Comment: Birendra, i am also use this but still getting nill on json object